# Serial Communication through Bluetooth ble

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, serial-communication

I am trying to communicate with my battery that has a ble Bluetooth module on it. the goal is to be able to connect to it and then communicate via serial communication by sending bytes back and forth

for example, I have a read and write uuid for it and some byte lines to send to it that it should send back bytes that I can interpret to read voltage temperature and current. like if I send the battery this EA D1 01 04 FF 02 F9 F5 in bytes it should send a byte line very similar back that tells me what the voltage is for the 4 different cells in the battery.

the things that I have are a service uuid and those bytes line commands.

I have tried using bleak as I have had some experience in this but for whatever reason it would not connect, I would get timeout errors or an os error.

I haven't been able to manually connect the Bluetooth with my Bluetooth settings on the desktop, so I haven't been able to setup a com port

I have been able to connect to it with a Arduino nano 33 but haven't been able to send and receive serial communication

I have been able to do this successfully with a Serial Bluetooth terminal on my android device and it works very nicely on that, but I would like to get it on my desktop as it would help me out a lot to automate getting that information and using it.

any help is greatly appreciated and i look forward to possibly communicating with some of you. feel free to ask for any addition information as maybe i was unclear with some things

Comment: @TomServo and you might want to look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) again, since it doesn't work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You want to become familiar with Bluetooth and need to understand that Bluetooth classic and Bluetooth LE are [different standards](https://www.bluetooth.com/learn-about-bluetooth/tech-overview/) that are incompatible to each other.

So while the Serial Bluetooth terminal probably uses the classic standard with [SPP](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/serial-port-profile-1-2/), other things you've tried seem to work with Bluetooth LE. The battery, for example, seems to work with Bluetooth LE and the [GATT service](https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/intro-to-bluetooth-gap-gatt/), as indicated by the service UUID.

All in all, it looks to me as if you should first familiarise yourself with the technology before you start writing your program.

Comment: okay so i think that I have gathered that my laptop with windows 11 is not capable to use the Bluetooth le protocol which is why its having trouble connecting to the battery, but not my phone. so i think to make it so my laptop can communicate with it i need some sort of device or a driver that can handle ble communications. Thanks for the links and hopefully ill be able to ask better questions in the future but for now as far as communicating ill look for something that can communicate over ble and communicate with my laptop